# How to store stemmed strings into single array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, stem

I am new to python and am just trying to write a simple program that would stem the words in a string and output an array/list that contains the stemmed words but I can seem to get them into a single array. This is the code i have and I included the output. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

ps = PorterStemmer()

new_text = "My two friends are getting married tomorrow and I could not be 
more excited for them"


words = word_tokenize(new_text)

for w in words:
    stems = [ps.stem(w)]
    print(stems)
```

My output:

```
['My']
['two']
['friend']
['are']
['get']
['marri']
['tomorrow']
['and']
['I']
['could']
['not']
['be']
['more']
['excit']
['for']
['them']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead.

```
print([ps.stem(w) for w in words])
```